# TypeScript error in undefined(undefined,undefined): Cannot find type definition file for 'src'. TS2688

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I'm pretty new to typescript.
This is what my tsconfig.json file looks like,
I don't even know where that "examples" come from

[image]

This is what errors I get in browser

[image]

This is my package.json

[image]

Comment: Do you have any TypeScript files under `src`?

Comment: yes I do have routes.ts, react-app-env.ts, reportWebVitals.ts

Comment: yeah I created it using " yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript " from [https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I found what was the error with the help of [this page](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27956), the problem was that I had a "@types/" : "fortawesome/react-fortawesome" specified which was not a @type

[image: Here is how it looks like in package.json]

So the solution was to remove the @types by doing "yarn remove @types/

Comment: Yes, and you don't need to install *typings* separately for [@fortawesome/react-fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome). It has its own built-in *type* declarations.